# WordPress Theme File Structure

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, structure, organization

As far as I know any single[-post-type].php, page[-page-slug].php and archive[-post-type].php files should live in the root directory of the theme folder.
Is there any way to put them in subfolders by category like so?

[image]